# Twilio to OnSip app error: Dial->Sip: SIP URI DNS does not resolve or resolves to an non-public IP address

Tags: javascript, xml, dns, twilio, sip

I'm using Twilio to build a SIP dialing solution for my company, and I'm receiving an error "Dial->Sip: SIP URI DNS does not resolve or resolves to an non-public IP address". I have a trial account at onsip to test the functionality, and when I call this account number it fails. The relevant TwiML is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Response>
 <Dial callerId="+15555555555">
     <Sip>sip:example@example.onsip.com</Sip>
 </Dial>
 </Response>
```

As far as googling has gotten me, I believe that I might need to whitelist my application. I also wondered that because I was using my application on localhost that was the issue, but I've used ngrok, and still receive the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible for Twilio to interact with OnSip because of the known issue laid out in this issue: https://support.onsip.com/hc/en-us/articles/204599674-Twillio-and-SRV 
Hope this spares someone else a headache.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way around this issue using Twilio's newly implemented [functions](https://www.twilio.com/functions).

Something like this should work--

```
const dns = require('dns');

let sipUri = 'xxxxx@onsip.com';
let protocol = 'udp';
let region = 'us2' ;

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {    
  var user =   sipUri.split('@')[0];  
  var host =   sipUri.split('@')[1];  

  // generate the TwiML to tell Twilio how to forward this call
  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

  const dial = twiml.dial();

  dns.resolveSrv('_sip._'+protocol+'.'+host, (err, addresses) => {
    var resolvedhost = addresses[0].name+':'+addresses[0].port;
    dial.sip('sip:'+user+'@'+resolvedhost+';region='+region);
    console.log(twiml.toString());
    // return the TwiML
    callback(null, twiml);
  });
};
```

This manually queries the hostname for SRV records and then uses the first result returned. Does not take weight and priorities into account.

[Nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v6.x/api/dns.html#dns_dns_resolvesrv_hostname_callback)